# ffmpeg encoded mp4 won't play in safari, works in chrome & ff

Tags: video, ffmpeg, safari

like the title says, I'm encoding a video from ffmpeg and it plays fine in chrome & ff but not safari.  Anyone know why, what to try, etc?

I followed the advice in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591959/mp4-with-pixel-format-yuvj420p-wont-play-in-chrome-17-but-plays-in-safari-ie) to no avail.

ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=$1 -i $2 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]scale2ref[c][v];[c][v]overlay=shortest=1[j];[j]scale=134:80" $3_120-3x.mp4
```

Most of that is just adding a background color to a video that has alpha transparency.  The `-vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p` piece seems to be what's important (btw without that it doesn't play in FF either).

result of `ffprobe`:

```
ffprobe version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'alarm_clock_120-3x.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
  Duration: 00:00:05.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 144 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 600x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 5:3], 140 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

Also won't play in mobile chrome/safari

Comment: Add `-movflags +faststart`. You may have to switch to Main profile `-profile:v main`

Answer (score 3):

As @Gyan said in a comment, `-profile:v main` apparently matters for Safari.

Just came from adding `-pix_fmt yuv420p` to get things working in Firefox. Firefox also seems to care more about whether the video is on the same domain or not.

Those two are apparently the final obscure pieces.

Comment: Omg, thank you! It took me hours until I came across this post. THANK YOU!!!!!! This question was written in 2017, this answer in early 2020 and late 2023 it was immensely helpful for me.